# query gives the same result multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I am doing a CRUD and I'm doing the edit part, I have multiple tables that are related to each other by foreign key, like for example the table 'empleados' has the foreign key 'rela_usuarios' which belongs to the usuarios table and I don't know how to relate them, so I save the query of usuarios inside a variable and put it on empleados as foreign key. Is that the problem is it another thing?

```
$ididEm= $_POST['idEm'];
$idPer=$_POST['idPer'];
$apellido= $_POST['apellido'];
$nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
$usuario= $_POST['usuario'];
$contraseña= $_POST['contraseña'];
$tipoCon= $_POST['tipoCon'];
$valCon= $_POST['valCon'];
$id_perfil=2;
$id_per_estado=1;


$sql="UPDATE personas " 
 ." SET nombre='$nombre', apellido='$apellido'"
 ." WHERE id_persona=".$idPer;
mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$sql="UPDATE tipocontacto"
." SET tipo_decontacto=$tipoCon";
mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$sql="UPDATE persona_contacto "
."SET rela_persona=$idPer,id_tipocontacto=$tipoCon, valor='$valCon' ";
mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$sql="UPDATE usuarios "
."SET username='$usuario', password='$contraseña', id_perfil=$id_perfil, id_persona=$idPer ";
$rela_usuario=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);


$sql="UPDATE empleados "
."SET rela_persona=$idPer, id_per_estado=$id_per_estado, rela_usuario=$rela_usuario "
." WHERE id_empleado=".$idEm;

mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
```

Also when I executed this all the other record got removed and got replaced by the last update

this is where the tables come from

```
$sql = "SELECT empleados.`id_empleado`, personas.`id_persona`,apellido, nombre, tipocontacto. id_tipocontacto,`tipo_decontacto`, persona_contacto.`valor`,
usuarios.`id_usuario`,`username`,`password`, perfiles.id AS 'id_perfil', descripcion  
FROM empleados "
."INNER JOIN personas ON empleados.rela_persona=personas.`id_persona` "
."INNER JOIN persona_contacto ON personas.`id_persona`=persona_contacto.`rela_persona` "
."INNER JOIN tipocontacto ON persona_contacto.`id_tipocontacto`=tipocontacto.`id_tipocontacto` "
."INNER JOIN usuarios ON empleados.`rela_usuario`=usuarios.`id_usuario` "
."INNER JOIN perfiles ON usuarios.`id_perfil`=perfiles.`id`  ";
```

Comment: This code is extremely susceptible to [sql injection](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/). You should use [prepared statements with parameter binding](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli).

Comment: With regards to your actual question though, could you explain exactly what you're attempting to do? Its not clear why you're attempting to update all those records at the same time, is your CRUD form really submitting updates for all these related tables all at once?

Comment: first make a select with all tables join so that you have all rows that shpould be update, and then use that to build an update with joins

Comment: @WesleySmith I'm trying to update all those tables because all of them make just one record, I have a join query with all of these

Comment: @nbk I edited the question, I put the join query, could you please give me an example?

Comment: It also seems that you're storing a plain text password via `password='$contraseña'`. You should _never_ do this. See [this article](https://dev.to/anastasionico/good-practices-php-security-how-to-manage-password-18bm)

Comment: @WesleySmith i will read it, i was thinking i was doing something wrong with the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your SELECT is correct, you can do following code, it uses mysqli prepared Statments with parameters, this prevents sql injection.

Like all code this must be **tested** first with test data to verify that all works as intended.

Wesley Smith also explained in the comment that you should **not save passwords** as **plain text**

so please read https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php and https://dev.to/anastasionico/good-practices-php-security-how-to-manage-password-18bm

I used the password hashing already in the code below, see the article how you can verify it in your own code

```
$ididEm= $_POST['idEm'];
$idPer=$_POST['idPer'];
$apellido= $_POST['apellido'];
$nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
$usuario= $_POST['usuario'];
$contraseña= =password_hash($_POST['contraseña'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$tipoCon= $_POST['tipoCon'];
$valCon= $_POST['valCon'];
$id_perfil=2;
$id_per_estado=1;
$query = "UPDATE empleados 
INNER JOIN personas ON empleados.rela_persona=personas.`id_persona` 
INNER JOIN persona_contacto ON personas.`id_persona`=persona_contacto.`rela_persona` 
INNER JOIN tipocontacto ON persona_contacto.`id_tipocontacto`=tipocontacto.`id_tipocontacto` 
INNER JOIN usuarios ON empleados.`rela_usuario`=usuarios.`id_usuario`
INNER JOIN perfiles ON usuarios.`id_perfil`=perfiles.`id`
SET personas.nombre=?,personas.apellido=?
,tipocontacto.tipo_decontacto=?
,persona_contacto.rela_persona=?,persona_contacto.id_tipocontacto=?, persona_contacto.valor=? 
,usuarios.username=?, usuarios.password=?, usuarios.id_perfil=?, usuariosid_persona=? 
,empleados.rela_persona=?, empleados.id_per_estado=?, empleados.rela_usuario=?
WHERE id_empleado=?;"

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $query)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssiiisssiiiiii",$nombre,$apellido,$tipoCon,$idPer,$tipoCon,$valCon,$usuario,$contraseña,$id_perfil,$idPer,$idPer,
    $id_per_estado,$rela_usuario,$idEm);

    /* Anweisung ausführen */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't knew all that information. What does that "ssiiisssiiiiii" parameter mean?

Comment: for every ? in $query you need bind a parameters $nombre is a string so so you add s to the second parameter From mysqli_stmt_bind_param. You have 14 questionmarks, 14 letters and 14 variables. s stands for string i for integer d for douböe b for blob see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php